# Extracting text subtitles using ffmpeg libraries

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I'm writing a C program that uses the ffmpeg's libav* libs, and using [Dranger's tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/), I can decode both audio and video correctly. Currently, I'm trying to extract subtitles. I actually don't want to decode them on time and display them on the video, but actually extract the subtitle text out of the container.

For example, on the cli,

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:4 -scodec copy out.ass
```

would give me the ass file back. (For some reason, srts only return the text.)

I've tried messing with AVSubtitle, avcodec_decode_subtitle2, etc., but they're returning the subtitles line by line. I would like the timecodes in srts, header information in ass, etc. All I want is the entire subtitle text file that was muxed into the container.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of .mkv files, you could use [mkvextract](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvextract.html). You may need to use `mkvinfo` first to identify which track you want to extract.

Since you want to do this from your own C program, you would probably want to use the [Matroska libraries](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/source.html#lib) instead of the command line tools.